# USB detection for linux OS using java

Tags: java

i am new for java. I need help to detect the USB event whenever user will plug-in to USB port.This should be worked out for linux O.S. using java.Please suggest me api which can full fill my requirements

thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121508/how-to-access-usb-ports-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

http://jusb.sourceforge.net/

Check this discussion also:

[SWT: Getting notified of a system device change (USB device connection / disconnection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765564/swt-getting-notified-of-a-system-device-change-usb-device-connection-disconn)

Edit1. Bare in mind that jusb is discontinued. However, it's complete source code is available on sf.

Comment: Hi Sterpu,
scenario is like, i am having USB hub which has multiple USB ports. when i will plugin device to port, java code should be able to recognize hardware interrupt.It should be worked when user will attach usb devices.

Comment: Well, jusb provides such capability. Take a quick look at http://jusb.sourceforge.net/apidoc/usb/core/USBListener.html. It's an interface you implement to get notified about usb events.

Answer (score 0):

Java 7.0 introduced the new API WatchService. Combined with the linux-command 'mount', i've found a working solution.

See http://arjenmaxnet.blogspot.nl/2014/01/detecting-usb-devices-with-java-70.html